# Pair of functions such that derivative of one is the other and vice versa, but they are not equal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question is whether or not there exists a pair of functions such that:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = g(x)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = f(x)
$$
$$
f(x) \neq g(x)
$$

or if there exists any relavent literature on this problem.

Comment: $c_1 e^{-x} + c_2 e^{x}$ for any constants $c_1 \ne 0$ and $c_2$. You need to solve differential equation $f'' - f = 0$, which has 2 general solutions: $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$

Comment: @Dmitry Post that as an answer, with a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions

Comment: @EthanBolker, I don't mind if you post it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply substituting the first equation into the second one, you get a necessary condition for the two equations you posted:
$$
f''(x)=f(x),
$$
which is a [linear differential equation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#.). Methods of solving such standard equations are well known and can be found in any standard ODE textbooks. See also this section of the linked article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case

For your particular case, a comment under your post has mentioned the [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Differential_equation_definitions).